# Optimize the linq query to sort the row?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I am getting the values from the database "Media" table by using the following query.Now i have to order the rows by its parent id means Firstly i have to show the parent Id row and then under it its child row like the following table:

```
ID   Name   ParentMediaId
3     C           null
1     A            3
4     D           null
2     B            4
```

How can i get the results like the upper table by using the following data table and modify following linq query with lambda expression?

Media table in Database:

```
ID      Name     ParentMediaId
1        A            3
2        B            4
3        C           null
4        D           null
```

Query to get the Data:

```
var dataset = _mediaRepository.GetAll().
                   Where(d => d.matter== matterId).Select(d => new
                   {
                       d.Id,
                       d.Name,
                       d.ParentMediaId,
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: the depth of relationships is 1 or may be greater?

Comment: ParentMediaId is its own foreign key

Comment: Yes but I means if it is valid something like this (`Id-Name-Parent`): `1-A-null`, `2-B-1` and `3-C-2`, here A is the parent of B and B is the parent of C

Comment: disallowing children underneath children

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `OrderBy` by `ParentMediaId` if the value isn't `null`; otherwise `Id`, then order by using `ThenBy` by `ParentMediaId` to make the parents appears first.

For the `OrderBy` you can use [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) (`??`). It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not `null`; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

```
var objects = _mediaRepository.GetAll()
                   .Where(d => d.matter== matterId)
                   .Select(d => new
                    {
                        d.Id,
                        d.Name,
                        d.ParentMediaId,
                    });

var dataset = objects.OrderBy(o => o.ParentMediaId ?? o.Id)
                     .ThenBy(o => o.ParentMediaId)
                     .ToList();
```

If childs appears first, then use `ThenByDescending` instead of `ThenBy`.

Elements will be ordered as follow:

```
ID   Name   ParentMediaId
3     C           null
1     A            3
4     D           null
2     B            4
```

Comment: Its not giving me the desired result ,its just firlsty showing all the rows with parentid and then rows don't have parent id.Please see in the first table i need the sorting order like the first table.

Comment: @ManjitSingh: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man @Arturo Menchaca ,It worked for me,you have saved my day :)